# AWS cli not working in Cron, but working in Terminal

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I've done a lot of searching and found a couple of people experiencing the same problem with Cron and AWS CLI, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I've tried reconfiguring the IAM, I provide full path information, I've explicitly defined the `$HOME` and `$PATH` variables in the script.

Here's the script: (Simplified)

```
export HOME=/root
export SHELL=/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/root/bin

echo "-------- Batch Moving to S3 -------- "
/root/.local/bin/aws s3 cp "$TMPDIR" "s3://$BUCKET/$DATE/accounts/" --exclude '*' --include '*.tar' --recursive� &>aws.log 2>&1
```

Works beautifully in terminal. However the moment it's run in cron, all hell breaks lose.

The `aws.log` shows this:

```
/root/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:369: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
upload failed: ./package.tar to s3://BUCKET/2018-10-14/accounts/package.tar can't start new thread
```

The top warning of the SNIMissing seems to happen when running in Terminal too, so I don't think it's the underlying problem when moving to CRON.

However this other error: `can't start new thread` - seems be be a Python issue (and AWS CLI runs in Python).

I'm calling my script via Crontab (running every 10 minutes now for debugging, otherwise it'll be once per week).

`*/10 * * * * /backupTmp/backup.sh >> /backupTmp/backup.log 2>&1`

I've checked the permissions and
`/root/.local/bin/aws` is an executable owned by `root`.

I'm using Python 2.6

Is there anything else that I could be missing?

Comment: I see HOME, SHELL and PATH: what other environment variables does "aws" rely on?

Comment: there's a suggestion from the software there `You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this`. why not try that? see Requirements from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

> Python 2 version 2.6.5+ or Python 3 version 3.3+

Comment: @glennjackman no other variables that I can see in the documentation - I updated to 3.6 and the error has been removed, still getting "Can't start new thread"

Comment: Found the problem, there is concurrency setting in the configuration of the AWS CLI tool, reducing this from 20 to 2 fixed the problem. Still doesn't explain why it worked in the terminal vs cron.